# Why "Unexpected Error" on UrlFetchApp GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

My code has an issue when run by trigger but running manually is ok.

i have the following function

```
var url = "https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls="+links+"&format=json";
 var getParams = {
  "method": "get",
  "validateHttpsCertificates":false,
  "accept": "application/json",
  "muteHttpExceptions": true
};
var stats = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,getParams);
     Utilities.sleep(3000);
   var cont = JSON.parse(stats.getContentText());
```

Running by trigger it logs "Unexpected Error"

according to my research i found that is an usual issue, i read that the rules to run manually are diferent than by trigger (even the ip are diferent)
"Apps Script uses two different UrlFetchApp pipelines: one for when the code is run by a user and one for when the code is run by a trigger. The trigger pipeline has some slightly different rules, which is why you are occasionally seeing these errors."

Well i think this is a serious issue and if google do it on purpose to regulate Fetch calls, i think is an offense for users and basically should not exist trigger service.

Any idea for the Solution?

Comment: Have you tried extending the duration after which the trigger is set to run?

Comment: The actual trigger is prudent...it is set to run just once a day.

Comment: Why are you using `Utilities.sleep()` before you parse the JSON?

Comment: This is because i read that sometimes the exec do not wait for json response.

Comment: If this is the same as GAS issue 4679 (https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4679) If you try this again you should find that it has been fixed now.

Comment: The Apps Script team has recently completed several internal changes that should significantly reduce the number of timeout and 'unexpected' errors caused when running UrlFetch from a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I am found a posible temporal solution:

```
Util.fetchJSON = function (url) {
var maxTries = 3;
var tries = 0;
var res, body;
do {
tries++;
if (tries > 1) {
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  Logger.log('GET %s (try #%s)', url, tries);
} else {
  Logger.log('GET %s', url);
}
res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
body = res.getContentText();
} while (!body && (tries < maxTries));
if (!body) {
throw new Error('Unable to fetch JSON after ' + tries + ' attempts: ' + url);
}
return JSON.parse(body);
};
```

But i dont know how to apply it to my original function: (help)

(this is a part of my original function)

```
 function soyEspiritual() {
    do {
    try {
    var pipe = "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=888ed60ff6a5ee79c05ec6963f6d3efe&_render=json";
     var pipedata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pipe,{method:"get"});
         Utilities.sleep(3000);
     var object = JSON.parse(pipedata.getContentText());
```